# How to removed crashed node in SQL Server 2012 Log Shipping?

Tags: sql-server, log-shipping

My DR site server crashed and they built a new one with a new IP.  I added the new node but I am unable to remove the old one (since it is no longer there).  The log shipping to my new node is working fine.  Any ideas on how I can remove the reference to the old secondary on my primary server?  Remove does not work since it tries to go to the server and remove the jobs related to log shipping on the secondary.

Comment: Similar issue here --> https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/101998/unable-to-delete-log-shipping-configuration

Comment: Thanks!! I did search but I was not able to find anything.  EXEC master.dbo.sp_delete_log_shipping_primary_secondary remove the old secondary did the trick.  The job was still failing but that is because when they set the job up initially they combined all 3 steps and used a linked server (that was no longer there).  Thanks so much!!!